# Does $f'(a)>0$ when $a<b$ imply that $f(a+b)>f(a) \impliedby a+b<c $

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives

Suppose I have some continiously differentiable function $f(a)$, such that $f'(a)>0$ if and only if $a<c$ ($c$ is some positive constant). Is it true that for all $b>0$, $$f(a+b)>f(a) \impliedby a+b<c?$$

My lecturer questioned this assumption. But it seems intuitively true: an epsilon increases in $a$ increase $f(a)$ when $a<c$. A series of epsilon increases should too, provided $a$ remains below $c$. Hence, a discrete change $b$ in the argument should increase $f(a)$ too. Is this true, and if so, why?

Comment: If $b>0$ then apply the MVT to the interval $[a,a+b]$.

Comment: @lulu.  What am I misunderstanding about the question?  $a < a+b < c$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x < c$ so $f$ is strictly increasing on $(-\infty, c)$ so $f(a) < f(a+b) < f(c)$, right?  Why do we need to apply the MVT?  I feel I must be misinterpreting what is being asked.

Comment: @fleablood  I think the OP is asking for a proof of the statement you are using.  Saying that $f'(x_0)>0$ quickly shows that $f$ is increasing in a neighborhood of $x_0$.  I don't think it is instantly clear that this means that it is increasing on the whole region (though that is undeniably true).  Worth a proof, in any case.

Comment: @fleablood  One needs something (though certainly less than the conditions of the MVT).  For example, consider the function:  $F: \mathbb Q\to \mathbb Q$ given by $F(x)=x$ if $x<\sqrt 2$ and $F(x)=x-1$ if $x>\sqrt 2$.  That function is increasing in a neighborhood of any given $x$.  Indeed, its deriviative (however you want to define it) is always positive (always $=1$).  Yet it is not increasing globally.

Comment: Fair enough.  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Mean Value Theorem, there is a point $x_0\in [a,a+b]$ such that $$f'(x_0)=f(a+b)-f(a)$$  But of course $x_0<c$ so 
$$f'(x_0)>0$$ which implies that $$f(a+b)-f(a)>0$$ and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question[1], it is obvious.

Forget $a + b < c$ and using the same variable $a$ in two contexts.  Let $d = a+b$ and you have $a < d < c$.

And you have the statement that $f'(x) > 0$ if and only if $x < c$[1].  Then $f$ is strictly increasing at all $x < c$.

So $f(a) < f(d) < f(c)$ when $a < d < c$.

That's it.

===

[1] (I may not understand what you meant by "I have some continiously differentiable function f(a), such that f′(a)>0".  It seems you are playing fast and loose with whether $a$ is constant or a variable.  But either way $f'(a) > $ **if and only if** $a < c$ *ought* to mean that for all $x < c$, $f'(x) > 0$, oughtn't it?)